# Definition of 'Koszul Ring' (in BGS)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the paper 'Koszul Duality Patterns in Representation Theory' by Beilinson et. al, they give the definition of a Koszul Ring:

A Koszul ring is a positively graded ring $A = \bigoplus_{j \geq 0} A_j$ such
that (1) $A_0$ is semisimple and (2) $A_0$ considered as a graded left $A-$module admits
a graded projective resolution:

$\cdots \rightarrow P^2 \rightarrow P^1 \rightarrow P^0 \twoheadrightarrow A_0$

such that $P^i$ is generated by its degree $i$ component, i.e., $P^i = AP^i_i$.

**My question is:** How is $A_0$ a graded left $A-$module? Is a module with $A_0$ in degree zero, all higher graded components equal to zero, where all higher graded elements of $A$ act by zero? (In other words, $A_0$ is not a submodule of $A$, but rather a quotient module $A_0 = A/A_{>0}$).

And: What does it mean for $A_0$ to be semisimple? Semisimple as a left $A-$module? (Which would be the same as being semisimple as a left module over itself?).

Thanks.

Comment: You are right, they see $A_0$ as the quotient $A/A_{> 0}$. As for the condition of $A_0$ being semisimple, they mean "$A_0$ is a semisimple ring".

Comment: That seems to mean 'The free left R-module underlying R is a semisimple module'. Thanks!